# Windows7 x64 Ruby 1.8.7 fork gem 1.0.0 error

Tags: ruby, winapi, rubygems, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to create a child process using the Fork gem (version 1.0.0).

My basic code skeleton is:

```
child = Fork.new do |child|
   ## something something something
   ##        loop loop loop
   ## something something something
end
child.execute
child.wait
```

That follows the sample code I believe but it always returns a very counter-intuitive error:

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fork-1.0.0/lib/fork.rb:237:in `fork': fork() f
unction is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fork-1.0.0/lib/fork.rb:237:in `ex
ecute'
```

I do have the proper gems installed:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.2.8)
childprocess (0.3.3)
ffi (1.0.11)
fork (1.0.0)
libwebsocket (0.1.4)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql2 (0.3.11 x86-mingw32)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.5.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.24.0)
```

I attempted to use the classes' future/call method combo but that doesn't seem to work for me either. I installed and reinstalled several times to ensure this wasn't an environmental issue.

I also tried to work with the win32-process gem but this requires an existing binary from what I can understand, to be called as a subprocess.  I really don't want to resort to cygwin but that might be the only way to address it.

What has been your experience with this gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't "fork" per se in windows, but you can call out to other methods using one of ruby's system calls: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes or win32-process or some other gem, or the winapi directly.

Comment: This is interesting topic.  I don't need a full process run, but I do need a "thread" to be created to do a trivial thing like connect to a database and run a query for instance.  I'll keep researching and see if I can figure something out.